# How to create a key value array from jsx form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
            <div className="form-group " >
                <input type="text" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="column_name" 
                    name="col" }
                    />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group " >
                <input type="number" 
                    className="form-control" 
                    placeholder="value" 
                    name="val" }
                    />
            </div>
```

I have these 2 fields in a JSX form. I want to create key,value pair array from this FORM with placeholder as keys and value as value for the key.

Comment: Please may you update the question to include a [mcve]? At the moment there's no code relating to state or submission.

Comment: using ref you can do it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-cdn-x2w6r?file=/src/App.js